# Applying superscipt/subscript tag using javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am displaying text from MySQL database which has a text like this "measurement of trace gases CH4, N2O and CO2 and the processes governing their production and emissions". The text gets saved through a text area. I wanted to apply superscript/subscript to CH4, N20 and CO2 using javascript/jquery when the text is displayed in the HTML Doc? Please let me know if this is possible?

Answer (score 4):

The simplest method is to process the data so that the digits are placed inside `sub` markup, e.g. CH4 becomes `CH<sub>4</sub>`. This, however, produces typographically poor results (including uneven line spacing), so I would suggest generating  `CH<span class=sub>4</span>` and using the CSS rules

```
.sub {
  vertical-align: 0;
  position: relative;
  top: 0.8ex; 
  font-size: 80%;
}
```

The values used can be tuned, of course, perhaps depending on font.

Other options include using subscript characters (as suggested in @TachyonVortex’s answer) and using OpenType features for subscripting with `font-feature-settings` (limited browser support, limited font support).

Comment: I have clearly mentioned that the text comes from  a database. I may not be able to hard code css classes. It has to be done dynamically. I need to search for text like CH4 and then make the 4 as subscript.

Comment: Of course, if the data is just plain text, you need to recognize the digits that should be subscripted and e.g. generate suitable markup around them. This is rather independent of the issue of selecting the markup or notation for subscripts, and it depends on the specific data (e.g., should any digit sequence immediately following a letter or a closing parentheses be a made a superscript?).

Answer (score 3):

You can use the subscript number characters in Unicode: CH₄, N₂O, CO₂.

- [Unicode Character 'SUBSCRIPT FOUR' (U+2084)](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2084/index.htm)
- [Unicode Character 'SUBSCRIPT TWO' (U+2082)](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2082/index.htm)

You could write a regex to match chemical formulae (eg: CH4) and reformat them using the subscript number characters (CH₄).

You have two options:

1. Store the text from the `<textarea>` in the database without any reformatting. Then when you render the HTML page, add the subscript numbers, either server-side (eg: PHP) or client-side (eg: JavaScript).
2. Reformat the text before writing it to the database.

Once the subscript numbers have been added, you need to ensure that you're using the UTF-8 charset from that point onwards, to avoid corrupting the characters.

Comment: This approach produces typographically optimal results when it works, but it may fail to work due to font problems. You would need use a font that contains subscript digits, and this may restrict the choices considerably: http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2084/fontsupport.htm